# Canvas is positioned above navbar

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

For some reason, my canvas is positioned above my navbar. I had it correct earlier and switched some things around and I can't figure it out for the life of me now. I want the page to load with the navbar at the top, and the canvas in the center of the page below the navbar. Is it something to do with the CSS or a misplaced tag somewhere? Thanks for the help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Square Up</title>
   </head>
<body>
    <style>
        .navbar-brand {
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-color: #00FA9A;
        }
        body {
            background-color: whitesmoke;  
        }

        canvas {
             border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
             background-color: #f1f1f1;
             padding-left: 0;
             padding-right: 0;
             margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
             display: block;
             width: 600px;
             top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
    </style>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-secondary">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Square Up</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="game.html">Play<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="instructions.html">Instructions</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </nav>

<body onload="startGame()">

<script>
var Square;
var Course = [];
var myScore;
function startGame() {
    Square = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    Square.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}
function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}
function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < Course.length; i += 1) {
        if (Square.crashWith(Course[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        Course.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
        Course.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < Course.length; i += 1) {
        Course[i].x += -1;
        Course[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    Square.newPos();
    Square.update();
}
function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}
function accelerate(n) {
    Square.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">Click me to move!</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below demo it should work for you, you can also add some class to canvas and give margin to it

```css
.navbar.navbar-fixed{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
} 
canvas{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Square Up</title>
   </head>
<body onload="startGame()"> 
    <style>
        .navbar-brand {
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-color: #00FA9A;
        }
        body {
            background-color: whitesmoke;  
        }

        canvas {
             border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
             background-color: #f1f1f1;
             padding-left: 0;
             padding-right: 0;
             margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
             display: block;
             width: 600px;
             top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
    </style>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark navbar-fixed bg-secondary">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Square Up</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="game.html">Play<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="instructions.html">Instructions</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </nav>



<script>
var Square;
var Course = [];
var myScore;
function startGame() {
    Square = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    Square.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}
function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}
function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < Course.length; i += 1) {
        if (Square.crashWith(Course[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        Course.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
        Course.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < Course.length; i += 1) {
        Course[i].x += -1;
        Course[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    Square.newPos();
    Square.update();
}
function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}
function accelerate(n) {
    Square.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">Click me to move!</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```